# Как вытащить все значения полей из субэлемента с помощью LinqToXml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq2xml

Вопрос по LinqToXml в c#.

Есть:
 класс Something

```
public class Something
    {
        private String id;

        public String Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        private String name;

        public String Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public Something(String id, String name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Something()
        {
            this.id = null;
            this.name = null;
        }
    }
```

Есть xml-файл, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Root>
 <Node>
  <Something id="1" name="name1"/>
  <Something id="2" name="name2"/>
 </Node>
</Root>
```

Собственно вопрос: как вытащить из этого xml файла List<Something> с полями id и name?
На SO нашел похожий вопрос, но для файла типа:

```
<Root>
 <Node>
   <Something>name1</Something>
   <Something>name2</Something>
 </Node>
</Root>
```

как сделать у себя что-то никак не впилю.

**Обновлено**

---

Что-то не получается. Делал так:

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    // что-то происходит
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(testUri.ToString()));
    }
```

И далее:

```
private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {

                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
// XML-документ сюда приходит, видно через пошаговую отладку

                try
                {
                    List<Something> something = (from node in xdoc.Descendants("Something") select new Something(node.Attribute("id").Value, node.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();
```

List не заполняется.

Навалял еще по быстрому тестовый вариант с получением XML-файла с локального источника:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

            try
            {
                List<Something> musicFolder = (from node in xdoc.Descendants("Something") select new Something(node.Attribute("id").Value, node.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Но аналогично, в лист ничего не добавляется.

Comment: Так а чего вы проглатываете исключения? Может хоть MessageBox туда, вдруг вылезет чё...

Или просто опечатка где-то в XML-е

Comment: Я ж через пошаговую отладку это все прохожу, если возникнет исключение, я его замечу. Исключений не возникает, в том то и суть.

Comment: Аж самому интересно :-)

Программа (`programm_xml`):

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");


        List<Something> musicFolder = (from node in xdoc.Descendants("Something") select new Something(node.Attribute("id").Value, node.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();
            
        foreach(Something e in musicFolder)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                
        } 
    }



Вывод:
![вывод][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/dN915.png

Comment: Все, разобрался. Суть была в том, что xml файл имеет вид: <Root  xmlns="ТутНечто">

Работать будет такое выражение: 

    XNamespace p = "СюдаXMLNS";
    
    List<Something> musicFolder = (from node in xdoc.Descendants(p + "Something") select new Something(node.Attribute("id").Value, node.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();

[Суть проблемы, решение на MSDN][1]


  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/bf061026-8dce-4845-8294-8acde88f4402/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
List<Something> entities = (from node in document.Descendants("Something") select new Something(node.Attribute("id").Value, node.Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();
```

Чтобы добраться до атрибутов используйте [XElement.Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute)